# Does moving a domain to a new registrar pose any risk to its nameserver setting?

Tags: dns, domain-name, nameservers, registrar

I want to transfer a domain name to a new registrar, but this is a live production site and I don't want anything goofy to happen to its nameserver settings. It needs to continue pointing to the same site without interruption. Are there any real risks in this regard when transferring a domain name to a new registrar?

In my case I am wanting to transfer from Network Solutions to Name.com and its nameserver settings are currently pointing to ZoneEdit DNS, which directs it to the webserver's IP. Hoping that the nameserver doesn't get unset during the process, leading to downtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it shouldn't. When you transfer the domain it should keep the same name servers.

One issue I've had is when using the losing registrar's own DNS. I've seen them remove the DNS records as soon as the domain is transferred away, which can cause issues. As you're using a third party for the DNS you'll be fine.